# X500Name to java.security.Principal

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am trying to look for the class that implements the java.security.principal to provide Subject DN values for certificate. While searching, I came across X500Name is the class that is usually used for providing subject. However this doesn't implement the Principal interface. What suprises me is that the depreciated class of X500Name called X509Principal implements this interface unlike X500Name. What class to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend to use a bouncy castle class: `org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal` which implements `java.security.Principal`. In order to get `org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal` instance you can use the method:

```
public static org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal getSubjectX509Principal(
    java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateEncodingException
```

of the class `org.bouncycastle.jce.PrincipalUtil`.

I give you a sample:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class X509PrincipalSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
            // certificate file must be encoded in DER binary format
            FileInputStream certificateFile = new FileInputStream("/tmp/cer.cer");
            X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(certificateFile);
            X509Principal x509Principal = PrincipalUtil.getSubjectX509Principal(certificate);
            System.out.println(x509Principal.getName());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

EDIT:

As you said, `org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal` is deprecated in the last bouncy castle release. So you can use `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name` to work with subjectDN fields, however if you want to use a class that implements `java.security.Principal` use `javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal`, I give you another example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.RDN;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.IETFUtils;


public class X500NameSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
         // certificate file must be encoded in DER binary format
         FileInputStream certificateFile = new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/aciffone/Escritorio/cer.cer");
         X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(certificateFile);

         // using X500Principal
         X500Principal subjectX500Principal = certificate.getSubjectX500Principal();
         System.out.println(subjectX500Principal.getName());
         System.out.println(subjectX500Principal.getName(X500Principal.RFC1779));
         System.out.println(subjectX500Principal.getName(X500Principal.CANONICAL));

         // using X500Name
         X500Name x500name = new X500Name( subjectX500Principal.getName(X500Principal.RFC1779) );
         // you can get the different subject DN values with BCStyle constants
         RDN cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];
         System.out.println(IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue()));

         x500name = new X500Name( subjectX500Principal.getName() );
         // you can get the different subject DN values with BCStyle constants
         cn = x500name.getRDNs(BCStyle.CN)[0];
         System.out.println(IETFUtils.valueToString(cn.getFirst().getValue()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks albciff. But the point is this class X509Principal in BouncyCastle is depreciated. The document says:" Deprecated.  
use the X500Name class".. And that is precisely my problem

Comment: You're right in the last bc release X509Principal is deprecated, sorry I make the example using and older version.

Comment: Hi @user907810 I edit the answer using another class, check it if you want. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Err, [javax.security.auth.X500Principal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html)?

> All Implemented Interfaces:

```
    Serializable, Principal
```